# Using the gcd to solve an equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I´m struggling with this question and it would be really helpful if you can give me a hint on how to solve it.

> Let $D=\gcd(a,b)$, $a = \alpha'\times D$ and $b = \beta' \times D$, all nonzero naturals.
>
> Find the possible $D,\alpha,\beta$ that satisfies $D^2\alpha'(1+\beta')=29106$

I've tried decomposing $29106=2^1 3^2 7^2 11^1$, so $D^2$ can only be $3^2, 7^2$ or $3^2 7^2$.
Another thing that I should mention is that $\alpha'$ and $\beta'$ are coprimes.

Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: I think you wanted 'how' instead of 'hoy'.

Comment: FIxed with another error, thanks

Comment: $D^2$ can be $1$.

Comment: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and $a$ and $b$ - any relationships there?

Comment: Now just list the possible values of $D$ and for each the possible values for $\alpha', \beta'$.  Check the $\gcd$ condition for each and report the successes.

Comment: I tried that. Just asking if there was a simplier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one extra case for $D^2$, which can be $\color{red}{1}, 3^2, 7^2$ or $3^27^2$. Notice that with $D\in \{1,3,7,21\}$, we have $D$ odd and at most one of $a,b$ even.

Now consider $e :=  D^2\alpha'(1+\beta')$, where we need to have $e= 2\cdot 3^{\color{red}{3}} \cdot 7^2 \cdot 11$

Can $a$ be even? No, since that would make $\alpha '$ even and $\beta '$ odd, so $(1+\beta ')$ would be even and $e$ would be divisible by $4$

Can $b$ be even? No, since then all multiplicative terms for $e$ are odd.

So $a$ and $b$ are odd. We need $(\beta'+1)$ to be even and a factor of $29106$, which gives $24$ initial possibilities for $\beta'$, starting $\{1,5,17,53,13,41,125,\ldots\}$ each of which will then give various detailed options on how $\alpha'$ and $D$ can be assigned against the remaining factors.

Comment: How it's amazing how much information you extract, thank you!